# How to make an image "float" over the buttons?

Tags: python-3.x, image, animation, kivy, layer

I'm starting to learn Kivy.
The code below generates a 10x10 button grid:

```
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = GridLayout(cols=10)
        for i in range (1, 101):
            layout.add_widget(Button(text=str(i)))
        return layout

MyApp().run()
```

[image]

Now, I'd like to add a png image to an independent layer, which randomly "wander" over these buttons, independently.

[image]

Then the user should click on the button on which the image is going, as in a game.

That is, the image should not be clickable and will be shown only visually over the buttons, meanwhile, the buttons should respond perfectly as if there was no image over them.
How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw the image in the `Canvas` of the `GridLayout` using a `Rectangle`. And the position can be updated using `Clock_schedule_interval()`. Like this:

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import Rectangle
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = GridLayout(cols=10)
        with layout.canvas.after:
            Color(1,1,1,0.5)  # if you want to see through the image
            self.bg = Rectangle(source='KQxab.png') # source is the image
        for i in range (1, 101):
            layout.add_widget(Button(text=str(i)))
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_bg, 1.0/24.0)  # schedule the image movement
        return layout

    def update_bg(self, dt):
        self.bg.pos = (self.bg.pos[0] + 1, self.bg.pos[1] + 1)


MyApp().run()
```

This code just moves the image in a straight line, but you can improve that.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.